# regular expression match word but can NOT be in a url

Tags: php, regex

I need to find a regex to match (global match) a keyword in a string and replace the occurrences of that keyword with keyword wrapped in a HTML span tag. However if this keyword appears in a URL like `http://keyword.com/asdfasdf` (the keyword could appear anywhere in the URL, not just the domain) then it should not match that.

Here is an example.

```
Keyword = 'yahoo'
```

Original string:

```
This yahoo that you call http://yahoo.com is nothing but yahoo.
```

Output string:

```
This <span>yahoo</span> that you call http://yahoo.com is nothing but
<span>yahoo</span>.
```

I will be using `preg_replace` in PHP if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since PCRE doesn't support variable length look-behind assertions (like `(?!=http://\S+)yahoo`) the simplest method is with a callback, e.g.:

```
$s = 'This yahoo that you call http://yahoo.com is nothing but yahoo';

echo preg_replace_callback('~((?:htt|ft)ps?://\S+)|yahoo~', function($m) {
    return isset($m[1]) ? $m[1] : 'span' . $m[0] . 'span';
}, $s);

// This spanyahoospan that you call http://yahoo.com is nothing but spanyahoospan
```

Comment: N.B.: If you're using a version of PHP less than 5.3 (please think of the children) then you'll need to define the callback function separately and call it like `preg_replace_callback('~pattern~', 'name_of_pre53_func', $s)`

Comment: FYI, the syntax for negative lookbehind is `(?<!`, not `(?!=`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you will not have ".Yahoo." any where other than in a url.we can have regular expression like

```
Regex - '(^| )yahoo( |\.|$|!)|(^| \.)yahoo( |$|!)'
```

The above accepts ".yahoo" or "yahoo." but not ".yahoo."

in preg_replace has an "i" option (which is placed at the end of argument 1) can be used to ignore case as well.

```
preg_replace("/\b$search\b/i", "<span>$search</span>", $string);
```